# Architecture patterns for low traffic and high availability web application

Tags: architecture, scaling, high-availability

We have an enterprise app which holds highly sensitive data and security is big concern so we ended up building a monolith on physical servers and now we are scaling slowly with few microservices but major chunk of the app is still a monolith

Because of our business needs we need to scale our app for high availability(99.999 uptime) **but unlike other systems we don't have high traffic.**

I Googled a lot but most of the materials are targeted around high availability with high traffic with high complexity.

Our Application stack

- RHEL OS,Rails,Mysql,phusion passenger

Even if you provide me a link to examples(with design) of such apps where above architecture is used that would be useful

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas to think about:

1. Make sure your web app is stateless (no data are kept in memory or disk on the web server)
2. Scale out your web application into a load balanced cluster/set of at least 3 nodes (check out nginx)
3. Test your application in the load balanced setup to make sure the behaviour hasn't changed/affected by the new infrastructure changes. (Should be fine if you fixed #1)
4. Scale out the database into a cluster of at least 3 nodes
5. Make sure you have a good setup for monitoring and alerts of any failure.
6. Chaos testing: take down web nodes or database nodes randomly and see how the system reacts and if any impact on availability and how to improve.